# Rating content from apex/visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, content, contentversion

Within a Visualforce page, how can I enable external community users to rate a Salesforce CRM Content document with thumbs up or thumbs down? I'm basically trying to create a custom version of the native functionality shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Thumbs up and down buttons on Content detail page]

A few dead ends that I've tried already:

- There does not appear to be a [standard Visualforce component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref.htm) which allows thumbs up/down ratings for Salesforce CRM Content documents
- There does not appear to be a [standard object](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) into which I can insert records to do thumbs up/down rating via DML, even though the `ContentVersion` object has `NegativeRatingCount` and `PositiveRatingCount` fields
- There does not appear to be an API operation or Apex method that I can call to rate a Salesforce CRM Content document with thumbs up or thumbs down

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do with the rest of the page, but a good start would be determining what objects are used for the thumbs up/down.

Comment: As technical evolution, Salesforce has revealed this object. Named "ContentVersionRating" available from version 42.0  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversionrating.htm

Answer (score 0):

Many approaches exists..But how about using Chatter Poles feature for rating your votes..

Comment: We had Chatter turned off, but we were able to get Add Comment - Users can add comments to content and rate content in Library. But I can seem to find how this is done.

Comment: That's supposed to say "can't seem to find how..."