# Rating content files in Apex

Tags: apex, content

Is there any possibility to vote for ContentDocument from Apex? Or maybe it is possible to enable this functionality in Lightning Experience? 
Which objects are responsible for votes management? I found where is stored number of votes, but didn't find any information WHO and WHEN have voted.
I saw this thread: [Rating content from apex/visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70695/rating-content-from-apex-visualforce?newreg=26b3093bae644075812b2e1b12224ab4)
but it's very old and didn't provide solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ContentVersionRating object revealed by Salesforce in latest version 42.0.

> **ContentVersionRating**
>   Represents a rating on a version of a file. This
>   object is available in API version 42.0 and later.

Just verified- I liked a content and queried in dev console as below and it returned result:

```
select id, Rating, ContentVersion.title from ContentVersionRating
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversionrating.htm

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I couldn't find this information.